# Unreasonable height of vertical swiper

Tags: bootstrap-4, swiper.js

I've created a vertical swiper inside a bootstrap 4 row and have applied height limits to the row. But the vertical swiper is going out of bounds.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 mh-50">
    <div class="v-swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-1" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-2" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-3" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-4" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-5" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-6" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-7" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-8" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-9" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-10" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 mh-50">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x100?text=Col-2" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <img src="//placehold.it/500x100?text=Row-2" />

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mh-50 {
  max-height: 50vh;
}
```

JS:

```
var vswiper = new Swiper('.v-swiper-container', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  speed: 2000,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 2000,
  },
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ogo3vcg/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem is that a child of an html tag does not get clipped automatically by the boundaries of it's parent. The example below models this phenomenon.

```css
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.clip {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; margin: 20px;">
    <div class="box" style="background-color: red; padding: 20px;">
        <div class="box" style="background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="float: left; margin: 20px;">
    <div class="box clip" style="background-color: red; padding: 20px;">
        <div class="box" style="background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can also see from the example, that the solution is to use the [overflow css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) which specifies what to do when content is too large to fit in its block-level container.

In your case, the quickest fix would be to put `overflow: hidden;` into the `.mh-50` class, however that would affect other parts of your project as well, so I would rather put that into a separate class.

Also, a couple of notes on other aspects of your markup:

- According to [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works) “in a grid layout, content must be placed within columns (`.col`) and only columns may be immediate children of rows (`.row`).”
- Similarly, content should be placed into `.container` or `.container-fluid` tags. (This will remove horizontal scrollbar from your example.)

With that said, your code could look something like this:

```js
var vswiper = new Swiper('.v-swiper-container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    speed: 2000,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 2000,
    },
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
});
```

```css
.mh-50 {
    max-height: 50vh;
}

.clip {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 mh-50 clip">
            <div class="v-swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-1" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-2" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-3" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-4" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-5" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-6" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-7" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-8" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-9" /></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100?text=Week-10" /></div>
                </div>

                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 mh-50">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/800x100?text=Col-2" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/1600x100?text=Row-2" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.6/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.6/js/swiper.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing the same issue with Swiper version 6.7.0. Here I am sharing my work-around.

I have made a tweak in CSS.

```
.swiper-container-vertical .swiper-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
}
```

I hope this may end someone's search. Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Man... You are save my time. Thanks